# Magento - show a module block in many pages

Tags: magento

i have created a module with a block that I want to show in many pages; for example : shopping cart, right column, and shopping cart with no-items.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the block to your layout wherever you want to see it. You can add a block to any handle like this:

```
<layout_handle>
    <reference name="parent_block_name">
        <block type="yourmodule/your_block_handle" name="block.name" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</layout_handle>
```

There's no reason you cannot do this for several layout handles.